# Accessing the Retry-After header in an API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-headers, spotify

I'm a newer programmer using React.js and the Spotify API for a music app. I’m trying to access the Retry-After header in a 429 rate-limiting error response ([Spotify docs here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/#rate-limiting)). This is my code currently, which I loosely copied from [this article](https://stevemiller.dev/2019/getting-response-headers-with-javascript-fetch/).

```
   async getArtistArt (artistID) { 
      let url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists?ids=${artistID}`
      let response = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
        },
      });
      let data = await response.json();

      if (Object.keys(data)[0] === "error" && data.error.status === 429) { // Handle rate limiting
        console.log('Error!'); 
        console.log(data); 
        
        for (var pair of data.headers.entries()) {
          console.log(pair); 
          console.log(pair[0]);
        }
        
      }

      return data;
    }
```

This is what I see in the console:

-

[image: screenshot here]

- `console.log('Error!');` // Logs 'Error!'
- `console.log(data);`     // Logs error object, but not the header
- `console.log(pair)`      // Error that says 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined'

I've tried not putting the response into JSON but that seemed to have no effect.

I've tried to avoid try/catch error statements as I’ve heard they’re somewhat outdated and not usually recommended, but would I need them to access the response header?

I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found where your error is. The code is almost correct except that you are checking for the headers in the `json` of the response.

Try to do `for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) {...}`, so that you are taking the response rather than its `json` content.

Comment: This is perfect -- worked like a charm! Thank you for your help and advice!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Could you mark my answers as correct then? Thanks!